# Expected rating when moving between leagues

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I have the following dataframe (info) on leagues and the players average rating (the higher the rating, the better the league) who moved between these two leagues:

| league from | league to | rating from | rating to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1320 | 1480 |
| 2 | 1 | 1466 | 1390 |
| 3 | 1 | 1420 | 1400 |
| 4 | 2 | 1380 | 1360 |

So as an example the first row: The players who moved from league 1 to league 2 had an average rating of 1320 in league 1 and then a rating (after some amount of time playing in league 2) of 1480 in league 2. So it is fair to assume that league 1 is stronger (harder to get a good rating) than league 2.

I have a lot of rows in the dataframe. Is there a way to mathematically express the expected rating for a player moving from one league to another?

Ideally I would like to be able to create a 'strength' list like (the numbers in the following table are random):

| league | rating |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1470 |
| 3 | 1450 |
| 2 | 1350 |
| 4 | 1340 |

Hopefully someone has an idea :)

Comment: In my opinion, as a real world problem, this is very tricky.  To some extent it analogizes to having a MLB National League player have his batting average rise when he switches to the American League, with its designated hitter.  There are several questions/decisions that you have to make, that I consider to be complex and (arguably) subjective.  For one thing, is the transition from the stronger league to the weaker league actually represent the reversal of transitioning from the weaker league?

Comment: That is, if you expect one player's rating to increase by $n$ points, do you expect another player's rating to decrease by $n$ points?  Another issue is what is the most meaningful way of processing the data.  Is it the average change (i.e. the mean), or is it the most frequent change (i.e. the mode), or is it the point where $50\%$ of the changes are below a number and $50\%$ of the changes are above a number (i.e. the median).  For example, in Olympic Gymnastics or Figure Skating scoring, the high and low marks from the judges are ignored, and only the middle marks are used.

Comment: Personally, in a real world setting, I regard the issue as non-Mathematical, and highly dependent on experience.  I am reminded of the movie *Moneyball* (Brad Pitt), where one of the scouts said to Brad Pitt (in effect) : the statistician has been working in Baseball for a few months, while I, the scout have been working in Baseball for $29$ years.  You (Brad Pitt) are listening to the wrong person.  In my opinion, in typical situations like that, I would very seriously consider the perspective of the $29$ years of experience of the scout.

Comment: Currently the 'rating system' is comparable within the same league only. You could have 1480 in rating in league 1 and 1480 in league 2, but the two players might be very different in actual skills. So the aim with this project is to make the rating system global for all leagues. The idea is to use the the player transfers to this task. If a player with a rating of 1420 transfered from league 1 to league 2, then if everything works, we would not expect his rating to jump around, as the rating system is for all leagues and not league-specific.

Comment: So the question is: With the info outligned in initial post. Is it possible to make a 'global' rating system on some mathematical formula/algorithm?

Comment: Resulting in the strength table outligned in initial post giving the expected rating for an average player in the different leagues in a global system.